# Access Win10 Partition using Linux Live Boot with Usb

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, bsod

Recently I got and error on Windows 10, receiving Blue Screens, and unable to boot Windows. I made a bootable Ubuntu LiveUSB, booted it, managed to find my Windows partition via command line (`dev/sda4`), but I don't know how to access it.

When I tried to open up the drive from File Manager, I receive this message:

> This location could not be displayed. Could not display all the contents of `Windows`: 
>  Error when getting information for file `/media/ubuntu/Windows/System.sav`: input/output error

What does that mean and does my drive have a problem (`Windows` refers to my drive)?

UPDATE: 
 I managed to get into my drive [`/media/Ubuntu/Mydrive`] via a terminal and retrieve my personal files.

[image: GParted]
[image: GParted all Partitions]

Comment: Google `linux how to mount ntfs partition` As a hint.. you will need to use the mount command with ***/dev/sda4***,  a target path like ***/mnt/windows*** (which you will need to make).. and possibly the file system you expect it to use.. good luck.

Comment: It is already mounted . In the file manager I can see it and on the right it says unmount. Which means it's already mounted

Comment: "the file manager" isn't the Linux way.. but you can't see any files when you click the mounted fs icon?  What file system?  Can you go to the directory (as root) and see the files then?  Type `mount` at the console and see what FS is being used ans where it is mounted.  Change to that dir and type `ls` to see the files.. I don't know what skills you have and don't want to insult you.

Comment: I managed to get into my drive's files . See the update i posted

Comment: Why are you trying to troubleshoot a Windows BOSD from Linux? To resolve, google the BOSD error code received _(it'll be all caps w/ underscores)_. You can also boot to WinRE to resolve via `SFC` or System Restore _(Windows will autoboot WinRE upon failing to load Windows 2x in a row)_.  If Startup Repair fails, you can either try to use System Restore _(Troubleshoot > Advanced)_, or attempt to repair via `SFC` _(Troubleshoot > Advanced > Command Prompt)_ > Determine OS partition `DiskPart` > `lis vol` > `exit` > `SFC /ScanNow /OffBootDir=C:\ /OffWinDir=C:\Windows` _(change `C:` accordingly)_

Comment: I have done it. All the six options in advanced options of WinRE had no result for me. All failed. All I can is open prompt or go to Uefi settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem using Chkdsk command on Windows. It repaired some bad sectors I think .
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

"Input/Output Error" on a specific file, e.g. `System.sav`, likely means that the disk has one or more bad blocks that happen to be allocated to that file.  Definitely run a check for bad blocks on that drive.  The Ubuntu disks tool may be used, the `badblocks` command, or any of several other tools.  You may end up restoring your system to a good drive from a backup.

Comment: I'm not familiar with bad block on the drive, but I rubbed smrtmontools on the drive and it says that Smart overall health self assessment test result: Passed. Do I have to check something else on the drive?

Comment: I'm not familiar with smartmontools.  I suggest a full surface check, as is available via Windows, computer, right click on the drive, properties, check for errors.  There is a full surface scan checkbox.  It can take hours, but it seems reasonable, given the symptom.